# Convert anything to string, including null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this snippet:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["somefield"] != DBNull.Value) {
                    tbSomefield.Text = (string)dt.Rows[0]["somefield"];
                }
```

Because

```
tbSomefield.Text = (string)dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]
```

fails if the value is null.

So I'd like a function, which can safely convert nulls to blanks.

```
tbSomefield.Text = nullstr(dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a method on `null` instance - that's one of the purposes of the C# 6.0 [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
tbSomefield.Text = dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]?.ToString() ?? "";
```

But specifically for `string` conversion, the most concise is to simply use the string concatenation operator which correctly handles `null` and does automatically `ToString` for you:

```
tbSomefield.Text = dt.Rows[0]["somefield"] + "";
```

Comment: And in both versions of your answer both null and DbNull.Value result in String.Empty

Comment: ... but ... is it possible for `dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]` to *ever* be `null`? Or is it supposed to be `DBNull.Value` in that case?

Comment: @user1892538 I guess if it never returns `null`, OP would not ask the question. Also being safe doesn't hurt :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I perfectly understand your point about being safe and of course I like your answer... but my (educated) guess is that the only real error behind OP question is likely a *`CS0029`: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.DBNull` to `string`*

Answer (score 6):

Use `Convert.ToString`:

```
tbSomefield.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["somefield"])
```

the `Convert.ToString()` method handles `null` and `DbNull` values correctly.

Comment: If it returns "" instead of "null"; I'm happy,

Comment: It returns `""` for `DbNull.Value` and `null` for `null` value.

Comment: "*So I'd like a function, which can safely convert nulls to blanks.*" => @IvanStoev 's one is the correct answer: see [here](http://ideone.com/mAjuI8) online

Comment: Ok, then I'll demote this answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer to the question in hand has already been given however, I can see there is a confusion on calling ToString() method on null objects.

If ToString() is called on a reference type the runtime will throw the NullReferenceException

```
Movie m = null;
string stringMovie = m.ToString();
```

above code will throw NullReferenceException on m.ToString()

and if the object is a nullable premitive type it will return an empty string like

```
int? nullInt = null;
string s = nullInt.ToString();
```

above code will return an empty string.

As the previous answers suggest that Convert.ToString is safe way to convert, it will return an empty string if the object is null.

```
Movie m = null;
string movieString = Convert.ToString(m);
```

Hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: but is DBNull.Value treated like null?

Comment: DBNull.Value will give us a singleton and System.DbNull.Value gives you a reference to the single instance of that class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToString()` to safely handle values

```
tbSomefield.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]);
```

**OR**

Another way is to use `conditional operator (?:)` [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
tbSomefield.Text = Convert.ToString((dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]) ? dt.Rows[0]["somefield"] : "Blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method as well to convert in string like below

```
public static string SafeString(this object data)
{
   //here goes your logic to check `data` is null or there is a white space etc...
}
```

Comment: No need to create an extension method. `Convert.ToString` will do all the work.

Comment: Yes i completely agree with you @PatrickHofman but this is for case where we wants to add our custom logic than it will helpful i mean it totally depends on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a "*way to convert anything to `string`*", **but** the kind of helpers I'd suggest to manage a `DataRow`.

What's important to note in *this context* is that C# `null` value **must** be treated as a special `DBNull.Value` when `DataRow` reads from DB.

The other thing - that is not really asked in the question - but I dare to add as useful IMHO is a generic, chainable extension

```
public static class ConvExt {
    public static DataRow ConvFromDB<T>
        (this DataRow DR, out T field, string col_name)
    {
        return ConvFromDB(DR, out field, col_name, default(T));
    }
    public static DataRow ConvFromDB <T>
        (this DataRow DR, out T field, string col_name, T blank)
    {
        field = blank;
        if (DR[col_name] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            field = (T) DR[col_name];
        }
        return DR;
    }
}
```

applicable not only to `string`, but also to different types like for example

```
string TestText;
int TestInt;
DateTime? TestDate;
```

the possible usage is (with an *optional* third default parameter)

```
DR
    .ConvFromDB(out TestText, "text_col", "")
    .ConvFromDB(out TestInt, "int_col")
    .ConvFromDB(out TestDate, "date_col", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score -1):

This does the trick:

```
        // Convert to a string or to blank if null
    public String nullstr(object indata) {
        if  (indata == DBNull.Value) {
            return "";
        } 
        else 
        {
            return indata.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the as operator:

```
tbSomefield.Text = dt.Rows[0]["somefield"] as string;
```

It won't make it blank but `null`.

Comment: This will produce wrong results if the value is an integer for example.

Comment: Haven't tried, but wouldn't that convert 123 to "123"?

Comment: And I don't want "null", I want ""

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Yes, isn't it supposed to? The original code did a cast to string. That would fail for an integer as well.

Comment: OP asks to "Convert anything to string", you are not converting the int to a string...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
tbSomefield.Text = dt.Rows[0]["somefield"].ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `ToString` with a `null` value?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Apparently they didn't. But if instead of asking *Have you tried this?* they put the question mark in the right place, it would have been a pretty valid answer :)

Comment: Lol, indeed @IvanStoev

Comment: 3 question marks with a final blank... but is DBNull.Value treated like null?

Comment: Question (for the downvoter of this answer or anyone else): is it possible for `dt.Rows[0]["somefield"]` to *ever* be `null`? Or is it *supposed* to be  `DBNull.Value` in that case?